# what is variable of this line of code and how to find the value?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am recently working on a project that needs to change this select function written in HTML. Inside of this, I find trouble to find these variables which named {L_PLSCHOKIND}, {V_SELECTED} and {V_MAINNAME}. I believe the other programme has put these variables into SQL code somewhere. Could you someone explain why these variables in {} and how this select tag get the value of the valuables. Thank you.

```html
<FONT COLOR="#3D3D3D" ID="dfont10"><B>{L_CATEGORY}</B> : </FONT>
  <!-- <FONT COLOR="#800000" ID="dfont10"> <B>{V_MAINKIND}</B></FONT><BR> -->
     <SELECT name="PJ" STYLE="font-size:9pt" onChange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
   <OPTION VALUE="main.php?{V_PHPSESSID0}"> {L_PLSCHOKIND} 
   <!-- BEGIN SHOW_OPTION1 -->
   <OPTION VALUE="main.php?T_PP[pdmain]={V_PDMAIN}&{V_PHPSESSID1}" {V_SELECTED}> {V_MAINNAME}
   <!-- END SHOW_OPTION1 -->
     </SELECT>
```

Comment: Those are php variables

Comment: As Seth said, PHP. Btw fire the one who has written this terrible thing...

Answer (score 0):

Brackets `{`,`}` are used to denote variables in php when you are inside a string instead of exiting a string to add the variable

```
$x = "this is the value of $y " . $y;

$x = "this is the value of $y {y}"
```

The big thing that makes this noticeable are the php variables listed such as `V_PHPSESSID1`

Long story short is your PHP is writing JS and injecting php variables as needed.

You can put the variables you are cursious about inside of a `var_dump()` in php or just try to `console.log` them out in js